# SSRS 2012 - Not interpretting HTML from Sharepoint List specifically the UNDERLINE

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013

I am running SQL 2012 in Sharepoint Integrated Mode.  We have a report importing a rich text field from Sharepoint and it is working fine for all but the UNDERLINE Tag.  I have seen information online that this is "By Design" from Microsoft and is handled with their styles? They don't show underlines because of how IE might interpret a hyperlink? Is there an easy way around this?  Thanks!

Comment: It's because "it could cause confusion for the user." What non-link text are you underlining on a webpage and why?

Comment: It's just standard underlines.   It's a rich text box from a SharePoint list.   We are trying to simply read the HTML from the field and interpret it directly.  It does for italics and bold, but not underlines.

Comment: Have you tried adding HTML underline markup instead of using RTF underlines? `<u>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behavior of Microsoft applications like Sharepoint you can contribute to uservoice where feedback is given directly to the developers.

Here is one that resembles your request:
https://microsoftforms.uservoice.com/forums/386451-welcome-to-microsoft-forms-suggestion-box/suggestions/16873060-be-able-to-use-basic-text-formatting-bold-under